# How to use constructor overloading in android?

Tags: android, constructor-overloading

I have two classes MainActivity and NewActivity which are going to access Main class having two parameterized constructors. MainActivity is doing well but when I call constructor having three parameters in NewActivity my app crashes. Unable to solve the issue any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
List<Main> lstMain;

ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lstMain = new ArrayList<>();
    lstMain.add(new Main("Image", R.drawable.album1));
    lstMain.add(new Main("Image", R.drawable.album1));
    lstMain.add(new Main("Image", R.drawable.album1));
    lstMain.add(new Main("Image", R.drawable.album1));

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, lstMain);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //View Pager reference
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}
```

}

public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView newRecyclerView;
List<Main> mainList;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
NewRecyclerViewAdapter newRecyclerViewAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

    mainList = new ArrayList<>();
    mainList.add(new Main("picture", R.drawable.food, 100));
    mainList.add(new Main("picture", R.drawable.food, 100));
    mainList.add(new Main("picture", R.drawable.food, 100));
    mainList.add(new Main("picture", R.drawable.food, 100));
    mainList.add(new Main("picture", R.drawable.food, 100));
    mainList.add(new Main("picture", R.drawable.food, 100));

    newRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.newRecyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    newRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    newRecyclerViewAdapter = new NewRecyclerViewAdapter(this, mainList);
    newRecyclerView.setAdapter(newRecyclerViewAdapter);
    newRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

}
```

}

```
public class Main {
private String title;
private int thumbnail;
private int weight;
private int quantity;
private int rate;

public Main(String title, int thumbnail){
    this.title = title;
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public Main(String title, int thumbnail, int weight) {
    this.title = title;
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    this.weight = weight;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public int getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(int rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}
```

}

Comment: You should attach crash log

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my answer, I've just modified one line of my onBindViewHolder method as follows;
replaced`holder.weight.setText(mData.get(position).getWeight());`
 with
`holder.weight.setText(String.valueOf(mData.get(position).getWeight()));`